# Links should be going down, rather than going right

Tags: html

When I list a set of links, they go left to right on my web page. I want them to be stacked instead, so going from top to bottom. What do I need to add to do that?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="Links" style="width:650px; background-color: #dcdcdc; border: #00008b 2px dashed;">
    <a href="index.html">Index Page</a>
    <a href="pagetwo.html">Schedule Page</a>
    <a href="pagethree.html">To Top</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to “*list a set of links*” then wrap those links in list-elements (`<li>`) within an ordered (`<ol>`), or unordered (`<ul>`), list .

Comment: To that point, the list elements aren't necessary, but the semantic distinguishing is correct and can be set with display types of `list-item` to  children respectfully, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to the links it will take the full width vertically.
    style="display :block;"

```html
<div id="Links" style="width:650px; background-color: #dcdcdc; border: #00008b 2px dashed;">
    <a href="index.html" style="display:block">Index Page</a>
    <a href="pagetwo.html" style="display:block" >Schedule Page</a>
    <a href="pagethree.html" style="display:block" >To Top</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to use a stylesheet than inline styles

Answer (score 1):

The quick way;

```css
#Links {
  width:650px; 
  background-color: #dcdcdc; 
  border: #00008b 2px dashed;
}

#Links > a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Links">
    <a href="index.html">Index Page</a>
    <a href="pagetwo.html">Schedule Page</a>
    <a href="pagethree.html">To Top</a>
</div>
```

The semantically correct way;

```css
#Links {
  list-style-type: none;
  width:650px; 
  background-color: #dcdcdc; 
  border: #00008b 2px dashed;
}

#Links > a {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<nav id="Links">
  <a href="index.html">Index Page</a>
  <a href="pagetwo.html">Schedule Page</a>
  <a href="pagethree.html">To Top</a>
</nav>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag belongs to the inline elements. With the css rule `display:block` you can let them behave like block elements.

```css
#Links a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Links" style="width:650px; background-color: #dcdcdc; border: #00008b 2px dashed;">
    <a href="index.html">Index Page</a>
    <a href="pagetwo.html">Schedule Page</a>
    <a href="pagethree.html">To Top</a>
</div>
```